# OS X conflict types for 'send'

Tags: c, xcode, macos, clang

I have some problems with compiling code on OS X 10.10 with Xcode 6.2.

> Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
>
> Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0

My program is very simple. Header file `header.h`:

```
int send();
```

I'm including this header in `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile it I get following error:

> .../header.h:12:5: Conflicting types for 'send' .../main.c:2:10: In
>   file included from .../main.c:2:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:574:9:
>   Previous declaration is here

```
ssize_t send(int, const void *, size_t, int) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(send);
```

Why I get this error without including `socket.h`? I know that solution can be to rename `send` function but I put my cards on the table, it's my homework and I must write it on Linux only with above declaration. But I want to compile it on Mac. Also I can create some macros to check operation system and rename my function only on OS X. The problem is that I will get later some static library and this solution will not work. Any suggestions? Maybe I have some wrong compile options or Xcode settings? Please help

Comment: the issue is xcode's module cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang on the command line works:
`clang main.c`

**The issue is the xcode's ModuleCache**. That seems to transparently include a lot  of stuff for you :D It passes the following flags to clang:
`-fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/dpich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600`

If you disable that in the build settings, it compiles fine:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple reasons you might get an error even though you didn't include `<sys/socket.h>`:

1. If it's a compiler error, it's probably because another header file you *did* include includes `<sys/socket.h>`.
2. If it's a linker error, it's because that symbol is linked into your executable, probably because it's a part of libc. Symbols are linked in whether you're using the header where they're included or not.

Your best bet would be to use a different name for your `send` function.

Comment: Would also bet my money on the "send" name is already used in <sys/socket.h>

Comment: `#undef` only works on macros. You can't use it to undefine a function, like `send()`.

Comment: Also I can't use macros define in static lib.

Comment: this is nice advice but no answer IMO: since the question is about xcode! -- I just tried his issue and just a main.c + a header.h is enough for a compiler error on xcode!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I think that the best solution to this problem is to add gcc to Xcode compilers in Build settings ([link](http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/add-custom-compiler-to-xcode/)) or use gcc + Eclipse with C/C++ Development Tool ([link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html)).

Comment: clang on the command line works fine so it IS xcode related. -- voted to counter uncommented downvote